# Facebook, Graph API: increasing dashboard counter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In legacy API it was possible to increase dashboard counter, but I can't find anything like this in Graph API. Is there a substitute for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier [this year](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/453) Facebook introduced the [Request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). Where the developer is no longer "incrementing" the request himself and instead only handle when the user respond to the request and "delete" it.

More about this can be found in the document and I've wrote a couple of tutorials about this:
[How To: Send An Application Request Using The Facebook Graph API](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/)
[How To: Handle Application Requests Using The Facebook Graph API](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/)